# Jquery fadein troubles

Tags: jquery, fadein

I have this code

```
<div class="img-thumbnail pull-left">
    <img id="female" src="public/img/femaleMini.jpg">
    <div id="imgOverflow" class="text-center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></span> Click</div>
</div>
```

I can't get the idea how I can normally show and hide div #imgOverflow. I need it to be visible when mouse is over the image and still be visible when mouse hovers over overflowed block. And hide it when mouse leaves img. Maybe it's some stupid question but I can't figure it out on my own.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply jquery mouseover , mouseout .example

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#female").mouseover(function(){
        $("#imgOverflow").css('visibility','visible');
    }).mouseout(function(){
       $("#imgOverflow").css('visibility','hidden');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H5Yy2/

Comment: Your jsFiddle doesn't work fully to the OP's spec - when moving my mouse from the image to the overflow, the overflow is still hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach a `.hover()` handler to the image and then a `.mouseout()` handler to the overflow. Here is one way to do so; note I'm using the explicit IDs from your markup but it could be make generic to use classes and referencing siblings if necessary for re-use.

```
$('#female').hover(function(){
    $('#imgOverflow').show();
}, function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(!$('#imgOverflow').is(':hover'))
            $('#imgOverflow').hide();
    },100);
});
$('#imgOverflow').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

The reason for the small (1/10th of a second) delay on the mouseout for the image is to ensure the overflow doesn't hide instantly. That delay gives the function a chance to see if what the user did was move from over the image to over the overflow.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6Y98U/

Answer (score 0):

here:

```
$('.img-thumbnail').on({

    'mouseover': function() { $('#imgOverflow').fadeIn(); },

    'mouseleave': function() { $('#imgOverflow').hide(); }
});
```

clicky for example --> http://jsfiddle.net/yEpgx/3/

note: this is for jquery v1.7->

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep her hidden div, put on your CSS:

```
#imgOverflow{display:none;}
```

and jQuery

```
$('img#female').mouseover(function(){
    $('#imgOverflow').fadeIn('slow');
}).mouseout(function(){
    $('#imgOverflow').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Example: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n6Nf2/)**

Comment: Same as others answers, your jsFiddle doesn't work fully to the OP's spec - when moving my mouse from the image to the overflow, the overflow is still hidden. Your use of `.fadeOut()` actually makes this easier to see.